# Javascript Slideshow slides overlapping when auto play

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, overlapping

I was making this automatic slideshow and it got this issue. I got 4 slides. When autoplay the first time it's overlapping the slide 4 with slide 2 and 3, it's only happen one time after site load. when the slideshow goes for the second time and when I use the dots in the bottom it's working perfectly fine without any issues.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var slidesl = $('.slideitem').length

var d = "<li class=\"dot active-dot\">&bull;</li>";

for (var i = 1; i < slidesl; i++) {
  d = d+"<li class=\"dot\">&bull;</li>";
}   
var dots = "<ul class=\"slider-dots\">" + d + "</ul\>";

$("#slideshow").append(dots);
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
var interval = setInterval(slide, 3000);

function intslide(func) {
    if (func == 'start') { 
    interval = setInterval(slide, 3000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);        
        }
}

function slide() {
        sact('next',0, 1200);
}
    
function sact(a, ix, it) {
        var currentSlide = $('.current');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slideitem');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev('.slideitem');
            var reqSlide = $('.slideitem').eq(ix);

            var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
          var nextDot = currentDot.next();
          var prevDot = currentDot.prev();
            var reqDot = $('.dot').eq(ix);
        
        if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
            nextSlide = $('.slideitem').first();
            }

        if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
            prevDot = $('.dot').last();
            prevSlide = $('.slideitem').last();
            }
            
        if (a == 'next') {
            var Slide = nextSlide;
            var Dot = nextDot;
            }
            else if (a == 'prev') {
                var Slide = prevSlide;
                var Dot = prevDot;
                }
                else {
                    var Slide = reqSlide;
                    var Dot = reqDot;
                    }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(it).removeClass('current');
        Slide.fadeIn(it).addClass('current');
        
        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        Dot.addClass('active-dot');
}   


$('.next').on('click', function(){
        intslide('stop');                       
        sact('next', 0, 400);
        intslide('start');                      
    });//next

$('.prev').on('click', function(){
        intslide('stop');                       
        sact('prev', 0, 400);
        intslide('start');                      
    });//prev

$('.dot').on('click', function(){
        intslide('stop');
        var index  = $(this).index();
        sact('dot', index, 400);
        intslide('start');                      
    });//prev
//slideshow
});
```

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Udara_Samapth/c1zevrLj/23/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things I noticed which are making your slides overlapping. Looking at your jquery/JS in a first place you are using jquery hide method but inside function `sact()` you are using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions which adds opacity classes.

```js
   currentSlide.fadeOut(it).removeClass('current');
   Slide.fadeIn(it).addClass('current');
```

That makes top and bottom items to start mixing at some point of opacity.

To handle this there are two solutions in my mind right now.

1. The easiest one is to add background color to item.

```css
.slideshow .slideitem {
  display: none;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

2. Another effort is to control opacity timings which needs some work on your JS portion. you can do that by adding delay on `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions.

Here is the working link for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/liquidcharcoal/gqyjph1a/13/

Comment: Thank you, but even in your fiddle,  it's still overlapping when the slides go for the first time

Comment: When I add a color background it shows slide 4 after slide 1, so it's goes like slide1 slide 4 then again slide 4

Comment: Did you follow any tutorial for this?